# How concat two dropdownlist in php (Yii) and search concat results?

Tags: php, html, yii

I'm just learning yii (one week) and I have two dropdownlist that capture month and year, but I need the search to be done with concatenated month and year and through a submitButton, how do I do it?

My code:

VIEW:

```
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'mes',CHtml::Listdata(Meses::model()->findAll(),'mesID','mesNom'), array('class'=>'form-control','prompt'=>'--Selección--')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'fecha',array('class'=>'alert alert-danger')); ?>

        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'anio',CHtml::Listdata(Anios::model()->findAll(),'anioID','anio'), array('class'=>'form-control','prompt'=>'--Selección--'));  ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'anio',array('class'=>'alert alert-danger')); 
        ?>

    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Buscar', array('class'=>'btn btn-success')); ?>
```

How I do it in the **controller**?
Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply by get value from submission and filter data dependence of condition like this:

```
    public function actionYearMonthSearch()
        {   $month = 01; $year = 2018; // Default values

            // get values
            if(isset($_GET['month']))
                $month= $_GET['month'];

            if(isset($_GET['year']))
                $year=$_GET['year'];

            // You can concat both by $concat = $year.'-'.$month; and then using it nested of month and year like updated_at => $concat....etc

            $model = YourModel::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
  'month' => $month,
   'year' => $year,
), array(
  'limit' => 5,
));

            // ... and any code you need too ...
        }
```

You need to read [Yii documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en) and look to [actions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.action), also [active record](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)

Comment: THANK YOU :D (I apologize for the delay in answering)

Comment: You are welcome mate :) if you find its helpful, I wish you accept answer :) Thanks :D